# How would “add folder” and “add file” would be translated in the shortest way into German?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, spelling, software

I would like to make a localization of the interface into German and have faced a problem in how to translate *add folder* and *add file*. The only translations, which I have found, are *Ordner hinzufügen* and *Datei hinzufügen*, but they appear to be too long. Could somebody suggest shorter phrases?

Comment: Whatever you chose, just don't abbreviate it... Pagemaker hat "Bearb." for the "Edit" menu for no good reason and it just looked ugly.

Comment: If the (correct) German text is too long, your application is not doing well in matters of i18n/l10n. Other languages will require even longer strings. It’s actually very likely that the platform you’re developing for has respective guidelines especially regarding such common terms, e.g. whether _folder_ should be transladed as _Verzeichnis_ or _Ordner_. Anyhow, these things would be mostly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ordner zufügen* und *Datei zufügen* ist kürzer. Noch kürzer wäre *Neuer Ordner/neue Datei*, aber ob das semantisch passt musst Du wissen.

Comment: Wenn es unbedingt noch kürzer sein muss, geht auch "+ Ordner" oder "+ Datei", das ist aber schon grenzwertig.

Comment: **Hin**zufügen ist nötig. Einfach nur *zufügen* klingt eher nach Rezept oder Verbrechen und ist vollkommen unüblich.

Comment: @Chieron: Das ist Quatsch, klingt nur für Dich so. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zufuegen

Comment: Es ist die zweite Bedeutung, ja. *Gebräuchlich* ist aber *hinzufügen* in Software (und vielen anderen Verwendungsgebieten) und *zufügen* in Rezepten oder Wendungen wie *Schaden zufügen*. Nur, weil es theoretisch geht, ist es noch lange keine geeignete Übersetzung in diesem Kontext.

Comment: @Chieron: Die Frage war aber nicht, was die gebräuchliste Form ist, das weiss der Frager schon, sondern was eine kürzere wäre und zufügen ist eine kürzere und weder auf Schmerzen, noch auf Kochrezepte beschränkt. Bei Hinzufügen findest Du im Duden übrigens die gleichen Rezeptbeispiele.

Comment: Eine Übersetzung, die zuerst einmal Stirnrunzeln erzeugt, ist aber kaum besser, als ein gänzlich englisches Interface. Wenn man es wirklich kurz haben will, sollte man ein Piktogramm wählen. *Neuer Ordner/Neue Datei* ist auch verständlich. *Datei zufügen* ist nur scheußlich.

Comment: @Chieron: Ich bezweifle aber, dass das außer bei Diri, bei jemandem Stirnrunzeln hervorrufen würde.

Comment: musst nicht persönlich werden. Wenn ich mich frage, welcher Depp das übersetzt hab, runzelt sich meine Stirn auch.

Comment: @Chieron: Im Ggs. zu Dir bin ich nicht persönlich geworden.

Comment: Oh doch, nicht weniger als ich. Wie auch immer, das hier führt zu nichts. *Datei zufügen* ist als Übersetzung zu bemängeln, weil es ungebräuchlich ist. Damit darauf weist es darauf hin, eine Übersetzung zu sein, die bestenfalls mit einem Wörterbuch angefertigt wurde. Verstehen kann man es, das ist aber nicht hinreichend.

Comment: Wo soll ich persönlich geworden sein? Würdes Duj auch "Einfügen, Ausschneiden" durch "Hineinfügen, Herausschneiden" ersetzen? Wieso nicht?

Answer (score 7):

When you translate (almost) any English text into German, you will find, that the German text is significant longer than the English text. There is nothing wrong with »Ordner hinzufügen« and »Datei hinzufügen«. This is absolute correct German and it is not too long.

Here are translations of some words you often find in menus:

> folder = der Ordner
>   directory = das Verzeichnis
>   file = die Datei
>   window = das Fenster
>   to add = hinzufügen
>   to delete = löschen
>   to open = öffnen
>   to cut = ausschneiden
>   to copy = kopieren
>   to paste = einfügen
>   to select = auswählen

**Important:**

When you create windows for messages, be sure, that the window is big enough to display the German translation in full length. It is a very common error in much programs, that message boxes are big enough for English messages, but too short for the German translation (because, as said before, German is almost always longer then English). The effect is, that German users can't read the complete message. The German text often is cut off. Please test it!

Example for cut-off message:
[image: abgeschnittene Meldung]

Seen today on my iMac:
[image: messages on an IMac]
Apples message boxes are big enough for 1 heading line plus 2 message lines. There is no way to see what is beyond the end of the 2nd message line. The box has an unchangeable size and there are no scrollbars.

Comment: Really? I haven't seen text cut off in at least a decade...

Comment: Keep in mind that articles aren't used regulary in application menus. @Robert I have seen this also many times...

Comment: @Robert: Ich habe der Antwort ein Beispiel hinzugefügt.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it like this:

- Ordner hinzu
- Datei hinzu

or even shorter

- Ordner neu
- Datei neu

hth

Comment: ＋１  the untranslatable *hinzu* nicely corresponding to “add” (as requested) and  *neu* (“new”) as a short, common alternative.

Comment: But it 'sounds' horrible, at least to me. I would certainly think a translation like this was bad or shoddily made.

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft localizes applications then they start always with the German localization. This is done because they get the longest messages and can treat the geometry of dialogs and message boxes sufficient when they done with German

So don't expect to shorten the text but enlarge the geometry when you plan to localize.

Comment: In my experience, french texts tend to be even longer. And apparently hungarian tends to have extremely long words

Comment: Well, I just wrote what I got from the support personnel of that company.