# Passende Übersetzung für "to trace"

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, mathematics

In einer App, die ich programmiere, soll ein Graph einer Funktion angezeigt werden. Nun soll der Nutzer zwei Aktionen zur Auswahl haben:

- den Graphen verschieben und hinein- und herauszoomen
- den Finger über den Graphen bewegen und dabei den Punkt des Graphen mit der entsprechenden *x*-Koordinate angezeigt bekommen

Casio bietet die zweite Option ebenfalls bei ihren Taschenrechnern an, dort wird sie englisch mit "Trace" bezeichnet. Ich konnte keine gute Übersetzung finden und frage mich deshalb, wie man dieses Wort in diesem Zusammenhang am besten übersetzen würde.

PS: Am besten wäre eine Übersetzung, die ebenfalls aus nur einem Wort besteht, da in der App nicht allzu viel Platz für Beschriftungen ist.

Comment: Zum Platzmangel: Deutsch braucht für dieselbe Aussage rund 20-30% mehr Platz als Englisch. Also solltest du generell die Größe der Ausgabeelemente an die deutschen Texte anpassen statt an die englischen. Die englischen Texte passen dann fast immer in die Elemente. Was passiert, wenn man das nicht macht, kannst du dir am Ende [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/29508/1487) ansehen.

Comment: Die Gröse der Container wird zum Glück automatisch angepasst, das sollte also kein Problem sein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie wäre es mit

> abtasten

oder

> ausmessen

(ersteres gefällt mir persönlich besser, vor allem auf einem Touchscreen...)

Comment: "abtasten" und "ausmessen" haben ganz klare Bedeutungen, die mit der hier gesuchten keinerlei Ähnlichkeit aufweisen. Es wird weder etwas gemessen (denn es kommt am Ende keine Maßangabe heraus) noch etwas abgetastet (allenfalls der Bildschirm, ganz sicher jedoch nicht die untastbare Abbildung darauf).

Answer (score 1):

Ich möchte zu den schon sehr guten Antworten eine weitere Möglichkeit hinzufügen:

> Graph untersuchen

oder einfach nur

> untersuchen

Comment: Der Graph wird doch nicht untersucht, denn es soll ja nichts über den Graphen herausgefunden werden. Er wird schlicht und einfach nachgezeichnet, oder der Nutzer fährt ihn mit dem Finger nach.

Answer (score 1):

Der Graph wird mit dem Finger sozusagen abgeschnüffelt, wodurch zusätzliche Informationen entstehen. Darum:

> - sondieren
> - detektieren
> - <s>abschnüffeln</s>

Weitere Möglichkeiten:

> - Details / Detailansicht / Details anzeigen
> - Detailmodus
> - Daten / Datenansicht / Daten anzeigen
> - Werte / Werte anzeigen

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt drei Verben, die die gesuchte Bedeutung besitzen:

- nachziehen
- nachfahren
- nachzeichnen

**Nachziehen** und **nachfahren** stehen in jedem besseren Wörterbuch:

[image: DWDS Eintrag für nachfahren]

Belege für **nachzeichnen** findet man in zahlreichen Büchern:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meine Vorschläge für Verben zur kurzen Übersetzung der *Trace*-Funktion wären

> verfolgen, folgen

Comment: Ich halte "folgen" auch für die beste Übersetzung, hatte jedoch gehofft, dass jemand noch etwas besseres findet...

Comment: Das kann ja noch kommen :)

Answer (score 0):

Wenn der Platz reicht würde ich; nachfolgend aufgeführte; zwei Übersetzungen verwenden:

*"folgen & nachziehen" ... evtl. "nachzeichnen"*

oder (aber das gefällt mir nicht so gut) *"folgen & rausfinden"(find out)*

Answer (score 0):

Es bieten sich an:

- verfolgen
- beobachten
- protokollieren
- hervorheben
- observieren